# netty proxy server transaction

Tags: java, spring-boot, proxy, netty

i'm new to netty and i would like to create a proxy server using netty that does the following :

_ upon receiving data from a client, the proxy server does some business logic that will possibly modify the data, and then forward it to the remote server, this business logic belongs to a transaction.

_ if the remote server return a success response then proxy server commit the transaction, otherwise the proxy server rollback the transaction.

[Data flow diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbW6B.png)

I have taken a look at the proxy example at https://netty.io/4.1/xref/io/netty/example/proxy/package-summary.html but i havent figured out a good and simple way to implement the transaction logic mentioned above.
I should mention that i have create a separate thread pool to execute this business transaction to avoid blocking the Nio thread, my current solution is to actually use 2 thread pool with the same amount of threads : 1 on the frontendHandler and 1 on the backendHandler, the one at frontend will use wait() to wait for the response from the backend thread.

Here is my current code for the frontend handler:

```
@Override
public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
    final Channel inboundChannel = ctx.channel();

    // Start the connection attempt.
    Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
    b.group(inboundChannel.eventLoop())
        .channel(ctx.channel().getClass())
        .handler(new ServerBackendHandler(inboundChannel, response))
        .option(ChannelOption.AUTO_READ, false);
    ChannelFuture f = b.connect(remoteHost, remotePort);
    outboundChannel = f.channel();
    f.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
        public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) throws Exception {
            if (future.isSuccess()) {
                // connection complete start to read first data
                inboundChannel.read();
            } else {
                // Close the connection if the connection attempt has failed.
                inboundChannel.close();
            }
        }
      });
  }

  @Override
  public void channelRead(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
      if (outboundChannel.isActive()) {

          //Executing business logic within a different thread pool to avoid blocking asynchronous i/o operation
          frontendThreadPool.execute(new Runnable(){

              @Override
              public void run() {
                  //System.out.println("Starting business logic operation at front_end for message :" + m);                     
                  synchronized(response) {

                      //sleeping this thread to simulate business operation, insert business logic here.
                      int randomNum = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1000, 2001);
                      try {
                          Thread.currentThread().sleep(randomNum);

                      } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                              e1.printStackTrace();

                      }

                      outboundChannel.writeAndFlush(msg).addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {

                          public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) throws Exception {
                              if (future.isSuccess()) {
                                  // was able to flush out data, start to read the next chunk
                                  ctx.channel().read();

                              } else {
                                  future.channel().close();

                              }

                          }

                      });


                      System.out.println("Blank response : " + response.getResponse());

                          //wait for response from remote server  
                      try {
                          response.wait();

                      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                          e.printStackTrace();

                      }

                      System.out.println("Returned response from back end: " + response.getResponse());

                      //another piece of business logic here, if the remote server returned success then commit the transaction, if the remote server returned failure then throw exception to rollback 

                      //stop current thread since we are done with it
                      Thread.currentThread().interrupt();                                                 
                  }

              }

          });

      }

  }
```

and for the backendHandler :

```
@Override
public void channelRead(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
    ByteBuf m = (ByteBuf) msg;
    m = safeBuffer(m, ctx.alloc());
    String str = m.toString(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

    backendThreadPool.execute(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            //System.out.println("Starting business logic operation at back_end.");
            synchronized(response) {
                int randomNum = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1000, 2001);
                try {
                    Thread.currentThread().sleep(randomNum);

                } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();

                }
                response.setResponse(str);
                System.out.println("Finished at back_end.");
                response.notify();
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();                 
            }
        }

    });


    String s = "Message returned from remote server through proxy : " + str;
    byte[] b = s.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    defaultResponse.writeBytes(b);

    inboundChannel.writeAndFlush(defaultResponse).addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
        public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) throws Exception {
            if (future.isSuccess()) {
                ctx.channel().read();
            } else {
                future.channel().close();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

this solution is not at all optimized since the server have to use 2 threads to execute one transaction. So i guess my questions are :

_ Can i (and if i can, should i) use Spring @Transactional on the channelRead method ?

_ how can i implement the logic explained above in a simple way using netty ?

I have also used JMeter to test out the code above but it doesn't seem to be very stable, lots of requests didn't even have a response with the above code at around 2000 connections and 250 max threads in each thread pool

Thanks in advance

Comment: When proxying certain protocols, you need to make sure the replies are send back in the correct order, at the moment, because of the way your randoms are called, this might not happen correctly

Comment: Thank you for your input. I have tested the server and the sender seems to always receives back the response that correspond to the message sent since the ChannelInbound and ChannelOutbound are clearly defined for every message.

Comment: In case you were wondering, the reason i put the thread to sleep at random time is because i wanted to simulate real server business operations, where certain operations can be faster or slower than others. And in the case of the server that i'm trying to create, the responses doesn't need to be in the correct order, i just need every response to comeback to the correct sender.